Python custom logger multiple modules with variable logger name
I have a Python program which uses the click package to parse cli arguments. The --process argument indicates which part of the program should be run. This is because I am using docker compose to create multiple containers, which run different parts of the program.
I am trying to figure out how to use logging with my setup. I have tried to create a global_vars.py file with a single variable and change the value of that variable during runtime.
The issue is that utils.py is imported by process_1.py and process_2.py. And by the time the logger variable is set global_vars.process_name is still None.
main.py
import click

import global_vars
from logging_setup import setup_logging
from process_1 import Process1
from process_2 import Process2


@click.command()
@click.option("--process", type=click.Choice([
    "process1",
    "process2",
    ]),
    help="Process to run",
    required=True
)
def cli(process):
    return {
        "process": process
    }


def main():
    arguments = cli(standalone_mode=False)
    global_vars.process_name = arguments["process"]
    logger = setup_logging(global_vars.process_name)
    logger.info(f"Starting {global_vars.process_name} process")

    if global_vars.process_name == "process1":
        process = Process1()
    elif global_vars.process_name == "process2":
        process = Process2()

    process.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

logging_setup.py
import logging
import os
from json_formatter import JSONFormatter

def setup_logging(process_name):
    logger = logging.getLogger(process_name)

    # If the logger already has handlers, it's already been set up. Just return it.
    if logger.hasHandlers():
        return logger

    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    
    # Ensure the log directory exists
    log_directory = 'logs'
    os.makedirs(log_directory, exist_ok=True)
    
    # Define the file handler
    log_file = os.path.join(log_directory, f'{process_name}.log')
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file)
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    
    # Define the stream handler (optional)
    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    stream_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    
    # Define the JSON formatter and add it to the handlers
    json_formatter = JSONFormatter()
    file_handler.setFormatter(json_formatter)
    stream_handler.setFormatter(json_formatter)
    
    # Add the handlers to the logger
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
    
    return logger

utils.py
import logging

import global_vars

logger = logging.getLogger(global_vars.process_name)

def random_string(length):
    import random
    import string
    random_string = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for i in range(length))
    logger.debug('Random string generated: ' + random_string)
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for i in range(length))

I've got it to work by moving import down within main.py but I feel like there might be a better solution. Is there an elegant way to solve this issue? My preference would be to just have to run logger = logging.getLogger(global_vars.process_name) inside each module to create a logger instance.
